# Im trying to use my HTC camera on my pc Eclipse but im getting errors:

Tags: android

This is the content of the file: MainActivity.xml

```
package com.example.camera_test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
            int i = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            TextView age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            age.setText(i);
            startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
        }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

It was working good I clicked the button and it opened the camera application on my device !
But as soon as I added this lines:

```
int i = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            TextView age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            age.setText(i);
```

Im getting the error on my device say nned to force close.

I tried also instead age.setText(I); this:

```
age.setText(Integer.toString(i));
```

I tried instead of id.textView1 also id.button1 but not working.

This is the content of activity_main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="Activate The Camera" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the only two files I did changes.

Comment: Patrik no I started created a new project updated my question with that. I can make I did that on button click it will open the camera application on my device ! but I can't find how to show a message also when I click the button that will show how many cameras I have on the device. Im getting on my device when clicking the button an error say need to force close it if I move this 3 lines of the numberofcameras it will work good again.

Comment: I also had an error on the code it self when added the line: int i = Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); so I fixed it by adding above it the line: @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override anyway so far nothing worked cant show the message to show the number of cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Solution. Now when I click the button I see the camera then take a photo click on Done then I see the image I took on a small window in my device !

This is the MainActivity.Java fileL:

```
package com.example.camera_test;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );

            startActivityForResult( intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST );
        }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  
        // do something
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }  
       }  
}
```

And added to the activity_main.xml file imageView1 in the bottom:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="Activate The Camera" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now it's all working ! Thanks.